# What is the correct form of the conservation of mass equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

What is the correct form of the continuity equation
for a continuum body $\mathscr{B}$
whose particles are
fixed, and occupies volume $V(t)$ at time $t$?
\begin{align}
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\int_\mathscr{B}
 {\rho\mathrm{d}\Omega}=0\\
 \end{align}or\begin{align}
 &\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\int_{V(t)}
 {\rho\mathrm{d}V}=0
\end{align}?

$\mathscr{d}\Omega$ is the volume element in the material coordinate (e.g., a curvilinear
coordinate system $X_i$ attached to the body), and $\mathrm{d}V$ is the volume element in
the spatial coordinates denoted by $x_i$.

**P.S.**

The two integrals above are not equal, but we have
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\int_\mathscr{B}
 {\rho J\mathrm{d}\Omega}=
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\int_{V(t)}
 {\rho\mathrm{d}V}
\end{align}where
\begin{align}
J=det(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_j})
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The one with $\mathrm{d}V$. Let's take an example with a ball of constant density $\rho_0$ in spherical coordinates. Its mass is given by
$$
M = \int_V\rho(\vec{r})\,\mathrm{d}V = \int_\mathscr{B}\rho(\vec{r})\,J\mathrm{d}\Omega = \rho_0\int_0^Rr^2\,\mathrm{d}r\int_0^\pi\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi = \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\rho_0,
$$
where $J = r^2\sin\theta$, while
$$
\int_\mathscr{B}\rho(\vec{r})\,\mathrm{d}\Omega = \rho_0\int_0^R\mathrm{d}r\int_0^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi = 2\pi^2R\rho_0 \neq M
$$
**N.B. :** $\mathscr{B} = V$, since it's the same volume of the same body, hence the volume form $\mathrm{dvol}_\mathscr{B}(\vec{r}) = \mathrm{d}^3\vec{r} = \mathrm{d}V = J\mathrm{d}\Omega$, where the Jacobian $J$ connects the different parametrizations of the said volume. Naturally, you can apply this reasoning to other spaces than $\mathbb{R}^3$.